# How can I recreate 'docker run' using the remote API?

Tags: docker, remoteapi

What do the remote API calls look like to do the equivalent of, say

```
$ docker run -d our-image
```

There's a high-level view of what `docker run` is doing [here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.18/#31-inside-docker-run), and this is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776415/what-is-equivalent-remote-api-command-to-docker-run-d).

I've tried coping the `ContainerConfig` portion of:

```
curl -X GET 'http://0.0.0.0:2375/images/our-image/json'
```

To this call:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d $CONTAINER_CONFIG 'http://0.0.0.0:2375/containers/create'
```

And then doing a `docker run our-image` and comparing, for both respective containers created, the output of:

```
curl -X GET 'http://0.0.0.0:2375/containers/<container-id>/json'
```

And I notice some fields like `HostnamePath`, and `LogPath` which are set in the version launched with `docker run`.

Comment: Have you studied the source code of [docker-compose](https://github.com/docker/compose) -- This is written in Python and uses the [docker-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docker-py) python library which is a library around the Docket Remote API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to collect detailed information about the parameters passed from Docker client to Docker daemon. If so, try to use this workaround:

```
cd /var/run
sudo mv docker.sock docker.sock.orig
sudo socat -v UNIX-LISTEN:/var/run/docker.sock,group=docker,perm=0660,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock.orig
```

This command will dump all the client requests as JSON objects.